# ¿Es posible ocultar mi género en Internet al hablar en español?

Tags: género, neutralidad-de-género

He notado que en inglés existen ciertas formas de enmascarar el género de alguien cuando se desconoce o no se quiere indicar. Por ejemplo, en sitios como [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) o [Interpersonal skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) se podrían leer cosas como

> I have a new intern/friend and **they** do this and that...

Usando una tercera persona del plural, para evitar usar los *he/she* de la tercera persona del singular. Con la primera persona del singular no tienen problemas, porque muchos de sus adjetivos no delatan el género del interlocutor.

En español el masculino es a veces usado como género "neutro" o como género para referirnos a un grupo formado por miembros de ambos sexos.

¿Existe alguna manera en la que pueda enmascarar mi género al hablar en español (en particular para el uso del lenguaje que se hace en las nuevas tecnologías, como Internet)? Por ejemplo, en lugar de decir

> Estoy completamente **seguro** de lo que digo

¿Podría usar algún recurso o circunloquio para no usar "seguro" ni "segura" (ni "segur@") que podrían dar indicaciones, aunque fuesen falsas, de la pertenencia a un sexo u otro?

Comment: Aceptada la espléndida respuesta de guifa, espero que eso no desanime a aportar otras. Creo que esta pregunta se presta a tener múltiples respuestas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el masculino es el caso no marcado, y el femenino es el marcado (singular y plural función casi de igual forma), pero obviamente eso no ayuda en Internet.

Hay textos que se han escrito en castellano en que se desconocen por completo si alguien es hombre o mujer (ahora no caigo en el nombre, pero recuerdo haber leído uno en una clase de literatura española romanticista).

La única forma de hacerlo sería, en cualquier momento de tener que relacionar un adjetivo con el propio ser, hacer una de varias cosas (cada una no valdrá para todas las situaciones, pero imagino casi siempre debe de ser posible ocultar, incluso sonando algo natural):

1. **Convertir el adjetivo en algún sustantivo**, modificando el verbo según necesidad:
   Estoy segura<sub>/o</sub> que… → Tengo la certeza que…
   Soy viejo<sub>/a</sub>. → Tengo muchos años.
   Estoy agripada<sub>/o</sub> → Tengo la gripe.
2. **Emplear otro sustantivo** al que aplicar el adjetivo, mejor si es más específico, epiceno o invariable en cuanto a género.
   Estoy quemado<sub>/a</sub>. → Mi piel está quemada.
   Soy alta<sub>/o</sub>. → Soy una persona alta.
   Soy profesor<sub>/a</sub>. → Soy docente.
   Soy senador<sub>/a</sub>.  → Soy miembro del Senado <sub>(a menos que seas [Bibiana Aído](http://www.rtve.es/noticias/20080611/ministra-igualdad-bibiana-aido-se-ratifica-uso-del-termino-miembra/83911.shtml), caso no vale)</sub>
3. **Utilizar la forma verbal del adjetivo**, cambiando el tiempo o sujeto si es necesario
   Estoy enfadado<sub>/a</sub> porque… → Me <sup>he</sup>/<sub>ha</sub> enfadado porque…
   Soy licenciada<sub>/o</sub> en… → Me licencié en…
   Estoy interesado<sub>/a</sub> en… → Me interesa<sub>/n</sub>…
   Soy árbitra<sub>/o</sub> de fútbol  → Arbitro los juegos de fútbol
4. **Modificar la oración por completo**, la opción menos fácil pero quizás podría resultar lo más natural (no caigo en buenos ejemplos de momento pero en cuanto alguien me dé unos ejemplos en que las primeras tres no son válidas os los doy jaja)
   Estoy agotada<sub>/o</sub> → Necesito descansar. / [Me voy arriba](https://youtu.be/cmexg1sMs_0?t=49s).

Imagino en algunos casos sería necesario utilizar un sinónimo como algunos adjetivos carecen de formas verbales o sustantivales, mientras en otros, varias opciones serían posibles (por ejemplo, *estoy deprimido<sub>/a</sub>* podría ser tanto *tengo depresión* o *me he deprimido* o *me deprimió* según el resto del contexto.

Comment: _Me ha enfadado porque_ me suena raro, seguramente quisieras decir _Me ha enfadado **que**_.

Comment: @fedorqui pues sí y no.  Si hay algo que nos ha enfadado a que ya hicimos referencia, no sonaría mal.  Algo tipo, «sabes que este hombre me habló ayer. (y ello o él) me ha enfadado porque pensaba pero de verdad que él me interesaba a mí.  ¿tú te crees?» ;-)  Pero a secas podría resultar raro, tienes razón.

Comment: Bien visto. Algo así como que usaríamos _porque_ como introducción de una frase completa, mientras que _que_ aplica a construcciones más breves, sin un nuevo sustantivo...

Comment: A todo esto, qué bueno el diálogo de _Kika_. Acabo de descubrir con horror que no la he visto. Espero corregirlo en breve

Comment: @fedorqui solo pensé en esa película porque acabo de verla de nuevo este finde (mis alumnos tienen que verla la semana que viene)

Comment: se puede esconder el genero de la tercera persona utilizando el pronombre relativo "quien" que carece de genero, o utilizar algun sustantivo diferente para definer al sujeto como en el Segundo ejemplo. lo importante es transformar al sujeto de la oracion a uno que tenga ambiguedad

Comment: Aparte de Bibiana Aído parece ser que ahora habrá que sumar a Irene Montero: [El “portavozas” de Irene Montero releva al “miembras” de Bibiana Aído](https://politica.elpais.com/politica/2018/02/08/actualidad/1518079927_468582.html) aunque no sabía yo del "jóvenes y jóvenas" de Carmen Romero.